# Deshabilitar la validación de elementos HTML5 en un formulario

Tags: validación, formularios, html5

En los formularios los programadores están usando inputs con tipos (`types`) de HTML5. Por ejemplo, para el siguiente caso se requiere el ingreso de un número de entre 13 y 16 dígitos:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" title="A credit card number" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia en la imagen, el explorador (Chrome en este caso), muestra una validación la cual quiero evitar ya que esta y otras validaciones las queremos pasar al lado del servidor y mostrar mensajes customizados.

¿Existe alguna forma de deshacerme de estos mensajes de validación generados por el explorador sin tener que editar manualmente cada `input` del formulario?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de deshabilitar la validación para formularios con HTML5 es añadir el atributo `novalidate` al formulario.

Por ejemplo:

```
<form method="POST" novalidate>
    ...
</form>
```

O sus alternativas correspondientes:

```
<form method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
</form>

<form method="POST" novalidate="">
    ...
</form>
```

**Referencias:**

- [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-novalidate)
- [Disable validation of HTML5 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements) (SO)

Answer (score 8):

Aparte de la opción `novalidate` que [César especifica en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/257/250), hay otra alternativa que también puede ser útil: usar el atributo `formnovalidate`.

Un botón de `submit` con el atributo `formnovalidate` tiene el mismo efecto que poner `novalidate` en la etiqueta de formulario directamente, pero tiene una ventaja añadida: puede haber multiples campos `submit` en un formulario lo que permite tener la opción de validar o no el formulario cuando se envía  (fuente: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate)).

Esto puede ser muy útil para, por ejemplo, guardar el formulario para continuar más tarde, o procesar algunos valores aunque no se haya completado del todo. Demo:

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" required />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellido</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" required />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar (con validación)" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Completar más tarde (sin validación)" formnovalidate />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, no había escuchado hablar de ese atributo antes, buen dato!